# How to modify class variable in a separated running process?

Tags: python, timer, multiprocessing, instance, instance-variables

I am trying to write a Python class method that execute for a fixed amount of time and modify a class instance variable during execution if needed.
For my project, I need `read_key` method in the following code to run exactly 5 seconds (no more no less).

During this 5 seconds, I use `getch.getch()` to try reading 
one character from the keyboard and assign it to instance variable `self.key`. Because `getch.getch()` will block the execution of its process until a keystroke is detected. If the user doesn't press any key in this 5 seconds window, let `self.key` be `None`.

So far, I can only think of using `multiprocessing` and its `join()` to realize this 5 seconds "timer" effect.

```
import getch
import multiprocessing

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.key = None
        self.read_key()

        # to check whether instance variable is successfully modified
        print(self.key)     

    def read_key(self):
        def scan():
            self.key = None
            while True:     
                key = getch.getch()
                if key == 'a':
                    self.key = key
                    print('updated self key to ' + str(self.key))
                else:
                    print('invalid entry ' + str(key))
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=scan)
        p.start()
        p.join(5)
        p.terminate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    A()
```

Running the above code, it does take 5 seconds to finish. If user presses <kbd>a</kbd> key after program is launched, I expect the print out to be:

```
'updated self key to a'
'a'
```

What I actually see:

```
'updated self key to a'
None
```

Apparently, even though  `self.key = key` is executed, the actual instance variable `self.key`. Any idea why and how to modify `self.key` if the user presses the <kbd>a</kbd> key?

Comment: thanks Jayjayyy, I managed to solve the issue using a workaround. Solution posted below.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to come up with the following solution using `multiprocessing`'s shared variable. Using a shared variable `detected`, I am able to detect whether user has pressed any of the special keys I would like to detect. Then I manually set the class instance variable at the end of the method to achieve the effect of having `self.key` attribute set in exactly 5 seconds.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value

```
def read_key(self):
    def scan(detected):
        while True:
            key = getch.getch()
            if key == 'a':
                detected.value = b'a'
            elif key == 'd':
                detected.value = b'd'
            elif key == 'w':
                detected.value = b'w'
            elif key == 's':
                detected.value = b's'

    detected = Value('c', b'z')
    p = Process(target=scan, args=(detected,))
    p.start()
    p.join(self.time_interval)
    p.terminate()
    byte_str_map = {b'a': 'a',
                    b's': 's',
                    b'w': 'w',
                    b'd': 'd'}
    self.key = byte_str_map.get(detected.value)
```